# Openssl command switch for automation of certificate signing

Tags: automation, openssl

I know that when working with openssl you can bypass the
interactive input by:

- -passin pass:whatever
- -passout pass:whatever
- -subj "/C=pa/ST=pa/L=pa/O=pa/OU=pa/CN=pa"

However when signing a certificate, like with:

```
openssl ca -config intermediate/openssl.cnf \
        -passin pass:whatever \
        -extensions usr_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 \
        -in intermediate/csr/www.example.com.csr.pem \
        -out intermediate/certs/www.example.com.cert.pem
```

I need enter "y" twice:

```
            ....
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:96:7B:52:E6:FC:53:53:F0:F3:D1:B3:EB:FB:5C:95:4D:73:BD:B8:5D

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, E-mail Protection

Certificate is to be certified until Jul 12 14:00:14 2017 GMT (375 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:y


1 out of 1 certificate requests certified, commit? [y/n]y
Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
```

*Is there a openssl commandline switch that automates this*?

Answer (score 2):

From `man ca`:

```
   -batch
       this sets the batch mode. In this mode no questions will be asked
       and all certificates will be certified automatically.
```

As an aside, `man openssl` has this to say about using `pass:` for the pass phrase argument:

```
   pass:password
             the actual password is password. Since the password is
             visible to utilities (like 'ps' under Unix) this form should
             only be used where security is not important.
```